# Extract the Exact word from the string using python

Tags: python, regex, split

I want to extract `_CD` from the below string `MUMBAI_SATARA_TIC_IND_MT_CD.xml`

please find the code given below, but, is there any other way to extract exact the `_CD` word?

```
text = 'MUMBAI_SATARA_TIC_IND_MT_CD.xml'

if "_CD" in text:
    print("True")
```

expected Output :-

```
`_CD`
```

How to extract `_CD` word from above string?

Comment: `text = text.replace("_CD", "")` ought to work fine

Comment: @Andrew not this type i want to exact the exact word `_CD`. in your code you are replacing  this words

Comment: Do you mean to match the chars other than `_` before the extension? `re.search(r'(_[^_]+)\.\w+$', text).group(1)`?

Comment: What does the rule look like? Get the word before the file extension? Can you provide some more examples or describe the pattern in prosa?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew your code words but output is `CD` but i want to output is ``_CD. can you please suggest me how to extract `_CD` output

Comment: When you did search for `_CD` you have already extracted it unless there are multiple `_CD`

Comment: You could at least try *a little harder*... you haven't even tried using `re` that you imported!  What exactly do you mean by extract though? You want the `text` to have `'_CD'` removed? Or you wanted just to get the `'_CD'`?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew It's Works Thanks you so much

Comment: @Idlehands wanted the `_CD` word

Comment: You shouldn't  have accepted the answer below as `CD` is an unknown part that you want to extract. Else, you question is plain unclear.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This should work without using the regex.

```
text = 'MUMBAI_SATARA_TIC_IND_MT_CD.xml'
if '_CD' in text:
    ext_CD = text[text.find('_CD'):text.find('_CD')+3]
print(ext_CD)

## text.find('_CD'), gives you the staring index of the substring '_CD'
## text.find('_CD') + 3, gives you the ending index of the substring '_CD'
## with that, ext_cd = text[24:27]

Output:

_CD
```

Answer (score -1):

```
import re
text = 'MUMBAI_SATARA_TIC_IND_MT_CD.xml'
text = re.compile('\w+').findall(text)[0]
text = text.split(text.split('_CD')[0])[1]
```

Comment: what's wrong with it?